# Jquery form reset function doesn't reset checkboxes

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, reset

I have a form that contains checkboxes, and from **the script** I check and uncheck them according to some requirements. at a certain point I reset the form `$("#formId")[0].reset()`, all inputs get reseted exept for checkboxes!!

I reseted the form but checkboxes didn't get reseted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It turns out cuz I was using `attr('checked', true)` I switched to `prop('checked', true)` and it worked.
- After some debugging I found that `attr()` adds an attribute checked to the input (`checked="checked"`) while `prop()` doesn't add anything.
  I also found that `prop()` is newer and was released in version 1.6, while `attr()` in version 1.0

### So I advice you to use `prop()` more often than `attr()`

Comment: Don't just "use prop more than attr" - use prop() when you want to change properties (such as checked) and attr() when you want to change attributes. If in doubt, use prop. But don't just always blindly use attr.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="cityForm" name= "input" action="#" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="cityName"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="city_1" name="city_1" value="New York">
    <label for="city_1"> New York</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="city_2" name="city_2" value="Alaska">
    <label for="city_2"> Alaska</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="city_3" name="city_3" value="California">
    <label for="city_3"> California</label><br>
    <input type="submit" id="citysubmit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" id="cityreset" value="Reset">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#cityreset').click(function(){
        $('#cityForm')[0].reset();
    });
</script>
```

Please check my code and let me know if you find any issue

Comment: It works in ur case cuz you're not checking/unchecking from the script, try and do it from the script and you'll see.